# Can not change some attributes with custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm customizing an UITableViewCell for my app, everything goes fine as I've done it several times.

Now I want to do some animation and problems come.

I'll explain it as short as possible:

I'm doing an dictionary app. I have a view which contain a UITableView with my custom cell (NTNHistoryCell), this view is for displaying history of user's researches.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HistoryItem.h"

@protocol NTNHistoryCellDelegate;
@interface NTNHistoryCell : UITableViewCell<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) HistoryItem *historyItem;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblWord;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDictName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTimeStamp;

//variables for editing
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgDeleteBackground;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *frontView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imgIconDelete;

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<NTNHistoryCellDelegate> delegate;

-(void)initLabels;
@end

@protocol NTNHistoryCellDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

-(void)historyCellIsDeleted:(NTNHistoryCell*)historyCell;

@end
```

User can swipe left or right to delete the entry.
There a two important things on the cell: a background as an UIImageView for changing color while user swipe, a frontView as UIView which contain some UILabels, frontView will change it's frame while user swipe. If the user do a swipe with a translation, the cell will be deleted (the entry correspond is deleted in the database too).

Now I want to do animation to let user know that they can swipe the cell by everytime the tableview is loaded. I use the event didEndDisplayingCell with the code below:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //do cell animation to inform user that the cell can be swiped to delete
    //only for the 1st row    
    if(indexPath.row == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row)
    {        
        NTNHistoryCell *cell = (NTNHistoryCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        CGRect originalFrame = cell.frontView.frame;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"move" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

        //move left

        //not working!
        cell.frontView.frame = CGRectMake(-originalFrame.size.width, originalFrame.origin.y, originalFrame.size.width, originalFrame.size.height);
        cell.lblWord.text = @"text change test";//not working!
        cell.lblDictName.text = @"text change test";//not working!
        cell.frontView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];//work fine!

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

It's not going well with all the code, you can see my comment, I can change the background color but the text of UILabel and the frame of frontView.

I intend to move left then move right the frontView.

Where did I go wrong?

Here is the screenshot in order to clarify my words (I haven't got enough reputation to post image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUddJ.png

EDIT:
I solved it.
See my comment in @danypata reply.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: @danypata No I don't, I turn it off for all the xib!

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to animate the first visible cell from your table view whenever a cell is displayed ?

Comment: @danypata Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: @danypata not quite whenever a cell is displayed, I want to animate only one time since the view that contain the table view is loaded.

Comment: So you want only the first cell to be animated, only one time, after the view (view controller's view or whatever ) is fully loaded ?

Comment: @danypata You got me! Appreciate for the comprehension. As I dont want to bother the user much, I want to animate only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is to detect when the table view has complete the loading process and after that do an animation for the first visible cell. So here is my approach:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  shouldAnimate = YES;
}

//delegate method
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  if(shouldAnimate) {
       if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
       //now the table view completes the loading process
       [self perforAnimation];
     }
}

-(void)performAnimation {
   shouldAnimate = NO;
   NSIndexPath *firstCelPath = [[yourTableView indexPathsForVisibleCells] objectAtIndex:0]
   YourCustomCell *cell = [yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstCellPath];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
     //do your changes
   }];
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that this approach will work but you should give it a try.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for being late. I did some try with your code but it's still not working til I do some trick and everything's fine!. Instead of just call the method by: [self performAnimation] I use [self performSelector:@selector(performAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0].

Comment: Really don't know why... Thanks for your help! :)